# sed unicode substituion file and string

Tags: unicode, sed

I'm using sed to translate unicode strings to some other flavour of unicode and with mixed success.

Can someone explain this. I have a file with an acute a in it that shows up as a blob character and also is rejected by software to display it.

If I try the substitution 
    echo Th�i|sed 's/\xef\xbf\xbd/\xc3\xa1/'
I get the desired result
    Thái

If I put the string into a file

```
echo Th�i > t1
cat t1||sed 's/\xef\xbf\xbd/\xc3\xa1/'
```

The result is

```
Th�i
```

The strings are the same whether in a file or echoed

```
cat t1|hexdump -C
00000000  54 68 ef bf bd 69 0a                              |Th...i.|
echo Th�i |hexdump -C
00000000  54 68 ef bf bd 69 0a                              |Th...i.|
00000007
```

I tried adding a character to the file in case it was something to do with and endian boundary but still the same result.

Can anyone suggest what I am missing please.

Comment: What happens when you read the file directly, instead of using `cat` unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Vehrs for asking a simple question.
For some reason cat of the file bombs howerve

```
echo Th�i > t1
sed 's/\xef\xbf\xbd/\xc3\xa1/' t1

Thái
```

and also works is

```
sed -i 's/\xef\xbf\xbd/\xc3\xa1/' t1
```